# Spotify No Public Repo Keys after Software Centre Installation (Can't Update through apt)

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, keys

After another user installed Spotify from the Software Centre, I noticed that I could no longer apt update as so:

```
Err:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45

W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

So I tried the man page suggestion:

```
sudo apt update --allow-unauthenticated
```

But that did nothing and nor did the apt-get version, so now I'm in a bit of a tricky situation. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I decided to try adding the public repository key and that alone resolved my issue (and allowed me to apply some very much needed upgrades to my system). Below is the command I entered to resolve my issue:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 4773BD5E130D1D45
```

This is one of the nicest thing an apt user can see :)

```
Fetched 6,131 B in 1s (5,112 B/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
29 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```